# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am want to know where I made mistake. WHen I click checkbox and select "Yes" option nothing happened, and I console mode I get this kind of error

```
function warning() {
            var Paid = parseFloat(document.getElementById("paid").value);
            var Total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('Total').value);
            if (Paid > Total) {
                document.getElementById('warning').style.display = 'block';
            }
            else document.getElementById('warning').style.display = 'none';
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            LoadList();
            TotalToPay();
        };
```

The error is saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
>       at warning (CreateManually:1377)
>       at TotalToPay (CreateManually:1372)
>       at window.onload (CreateManually:1387)

```
<div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Chapel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Chapel, "Yes", new { @class = "styled", htmlAttributes = new { @checked = "true" } })
                                        Yes
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Chapel, "No", new { @class = "styled", htmlAttributes = new { @checked = "true" } })
                                        No
                                    </label>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Chapel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-flat">

                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <p class="text-bold">EVENT DATE, ROOMS AND TIME</p>
                        <div class="heading-elements">
                            <a id="btnCalendar" class="btn border-teal text-teal-300 btn-xs"><i class="icon-calendar position-left"></i>View Calendar</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <fieldset class="content-group">

                            <div class="form-group hidden">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">contract id:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-9">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contractId" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Choose Date and Time</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-9">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control pickadate-format picker__input", @placeholder = "Date", @id = "date", onchange = "dateValidation()" } })
                                            <label class="validation-error-label" id="valDate"></label>
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-alarm"></i></span>
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeFrom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control pickatime picker__input", @placeholder = "Time From", @id = "TimeFrom", onchange = "vrijeme()" } })
                                            </div>
                                            <label class="validation-error-label" id="valTime"></label>
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeFrom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-alarm"></i></span>
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeTo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control pickatime picker__input", @placeholder = "Time To", @id = "TimeTo", onchange = "vrijeme()" } })

                                            </div>
                                            <label class="validation-error-label" id="valTimeTo"></label>
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeTo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

**The second part of HTML code**

```
<div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdministrativeFeePercent, "Administrative Fee", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdministrativeFeePercent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "AdminFee", oninput = "TotalToPay();" } })

                                    </div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdministrativeFeePercent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalesTax, "Sales Tax", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SalesTax, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SalesTax", oninput = "TotalToPay();"} })
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SalesTax, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TotalBudget, "Total", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalBudget, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", oninput = "TotalToPay();", @id = "Total" } })
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TotalBudget, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Initial Deposit</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Deposits, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "depositReceived", @min = "500" } })
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Deposits, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML. Looks like you don't have (at least one of) those `id`s you tried to select.

Comment: I possted, you can check

Comment: Yep, I do not see anything with `id="paid"` or `id="Total"` in there, or any references to those words at all

Comment: yo, in your warning function console.log your data and look what u got:)

Comment: And also `id="warning"`

Comment: The error message is very clear.. Line 1377, which is inside the CreateManually method, which is called from the TotalToPay method. Set a breakpoint on line 1377 and see why you're getting a null value and trying to read it's "value" property...

Comment: Guys, I add one more field second part of code.

Comment: The element with `id="Total"` is there but there's nothing with `id="paid"`